# Fitting a gjrGARCH model using ugarchroll: getting error + warning

Tags: r, for-loop

I get the following "warning + error" message that I want to get rid of but I don't understand it:

```
possible convergence problem: optim gave code = 1possible convergence problem: optim gave code = 1possible convergence problem: optim gave code = 1

non-converged estimation windows present...resubsmit object with different solver parameters...
```

My code is :

```
# Creating the specification with ugarchroll

library("rugarch")
spec_std <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "gjrGARCH",
    garchOrder = c(1, 1)),mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1),include.mean = TRUE), distribution.model = "std")

nsim <- 2 # number of simulations
nstart <- 500
simul_ <- matrix(rnorm(2000), nrow = 1000, ncol = nsim))

# Model fitting

gjr_sigma_std <- gjr_mu_std <- gjr_shape_std <- matrix(NA, 
nrow = nstart, ncol = nsim)

for (i in 1:nsim) {
  gjr_fit_std <- ugarchroll(spec_std, simul_[,i], n.ahead = 1,
                             forecast.length = 1, n.start = nstart, 
                             refit.every = 1,
                             refit.window = "moving", window.size = nstart,
                             calculate.VaR = TRUE, VaR.alpha = alpha)
  
  # Retrieving estimated garch variance, Mu and shape
  gjr_sigma_std[,i] <- gjr_fit_std@forecast[["density"]][["Sigma"]]
  gjr_mu_std[,i] <- gjr_fit_std@forecast[["density"]][["Mu"]]
  gjr_shape_std[,i] <- gjr_fit_std@forecast[["density"]][["Shape"]]
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Does `nstart -> 500` run ok for you?

Comment: Yes! that is just a simple variable with an integer as value.

Comment: the way its written, you're assigning `nstart` to 500 not 500 to `nstart`. Have you tried running it in the console?

Comment: I made a mistake when trying to write here a reproducible example but in my code it is correctly written. I will change it here.

Comment: Hello @JonnyPhelps any idea of What I shoould do to avoid this error? :)